# What era/country/manufacture is this vintage step through?

Tags: vintage

During my search, I’ve learned that this question can be very irritating for many. I think it’s because the asker is looking to make a buck or a fortune and their curiosity is empty.

Although I’d love to learn that I’ve just stumbled on a gold mine, my curiosity is driven by not knowing.

I’m an enabler for my retired mother. She mentions to me bucket list items and I help her ideas come to life. Last year it was to ride a horse again. This year it’s to ride a bicycle. So here I am.

She requested a single speed, low bar, big comfy seat, sub $200 cdn. I ended up buying this vintage step through. All bearings , pedals, brakes check out good and smooth. I’m replacing the rear tire and tubes and seat. The bike has been stored outside for the past couple years and the seat is saturated and now in a bag drying with a large desiccant pouch. So far I’m into it for $150cdn. I paid the kind lady her asking price of $75 for the bike because of its working order. Another $75 for a big soft seat, two tubes and a tire and large desiccant pouch.

The steer tube badge is missing. Front hub says wald. Rear hub says  Rigida. No serial number under the crank. No other markings on the frame that I’ve noticed. What makes this one unique is the double top-bar.

Should I just tune it up and tell my mom that I bought her an old blue bike?

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Matt

[image]

Comment: Classic dept store bike from the 50s/60s.  Could be Sears/JCHiggins, Western Auto, and a few others.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That makes sense. I like that it’s from 60-70 years ago and stood the test of being stored out in the rain for part of its life. I don’t think department store bikes made today, would last this test.

Comment: Please pay attention to the fork, it seems bended backwards (like after an impact) and it may be dangerous to ride (impact + possibly rusting inside, becoming **very** weak)

Comment: Hi, you’re right, it is bent. I’ll pull it off and have a better look. Great eye. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be the info you expect, but for your purposes, it doesn't matter at all.

Your mother wants to ride again, and that's fantastically awesome.  Anything that progresses the goal nearer to completion is good.

I suggest you find out if she had a bike in the past, what brand it was, what colour, and anything she remembers about it.  Perhaps conscript any other family to ask on your behalf so its a surprise.

Then paint the bike that colour, or fit a basket if she remembers having one.  Fit an Ahhooga horn if she remembers that.

Buy or make a set of decals that say the same brand as she had, or make ones that say her preferred name,  or even *MOM'S BIKE* or **BLIC** for `bucket list item completed`

You're doing a great job, keep it up.

Comment: Criggie, thank you for the reply. I get excited when I see a bike that resembles one I’ve had in the past as an adult or child.

Comment: @MattC me too - but then I cry on seeing the prices of Raleigh Choppers which are now worth more than my car.